# Azure Maria DB TX 2.0 Connect dosen't work

Tags: mysql, azure, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I'm trying to connect to my MariaDB TX 2.0 Cluster in Azure, but it dosen't work.
I create a public loadbalancer in the configuration step and after the deployment I get an ip address and an hostname.

example

```
mymariadb.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

mysql connect string:

```
mysql -h mymariadb.westus.cloudapp.azure.com -P 4006 -u myapp -pmypassword mydb
```

I get this error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
**ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mymariadb.westus.cloudapp.azure.com' (110)**
```

Any ideas why I can't connect to the MariaDB Cluster?

I tried also to connect to one of the maxscaller and from there to one database server -> this works.

Thank you!

**Update:**

thank you for the post. 
First of all it is not possible for me to run maxadmin:

```
Unable to connect to MaxScale at /tmp/maxadmin.sock: No such file or directory
```

I check the log and noticed that there is a problem with the listener

```
2018-05-15 20:18:03   error  : Creation of listener 'Read-Connection-Listener' for service 'Read Connection Router' failed, because both 'socket' and 'port' are defined. Only either one is allowed.
2018-05-15 20:18:03   error  : Creation of listener 'Write-Connection-Listener' for service 'Write Connection Router' failed, because both 'socket' and 'port' are defined. Only either one is allowed.
2018-05-15 20:18:03   error  : Creation of listener 'RW-Split-Listener' for service 'RW Split Router' failed, because both 'socket' and 'port' are defined. Only either one is allowed.
```

also find this:

```
2018-05-15 20:18:03   warning: Protocol module 'mysqlbackend' has been deprecated, use 'mariadbbackend' instead.
```

Hope you (as an MariaDB Expert) can help me with that issue!

Thank you and regards!

**UPDATE 2**

This is my cnf file (I didn't make any changes). This should be correct and work, right?

```
[CLI]
type=service
router=cli


[RW Split Listener]
type=listener
service=RW Split Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4006
socket=/var/lib/maxscale/rwsplit.sock

[Write Connection Listener]
type=listener
service=Write Connection Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4007
socket=/var/lib/maxscale/writeconn.sock

[Read Connection Listener]
type=listener
service=Read Connection Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4008
socket=/var/lib/maxscale/readconn.sock

[CLI Listener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
socket=/tmp/maxadmin.sock

[MaxInfo]
type=service
router=maxinfo

[MaxInfo JSON Listener]
type=listener
service=MaxInfo
protocol=HTTPD
port=8003
address=localhost


[db1]
type=server
address=172.16.4.4
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[db2]
type=server
address=172.16.4.5
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[db3]
type=server
address=172.16.4.6
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend
```

**UPDATE 3:**

I make the changes you suggested and tried to work with maxadmin command:

```
2018-05-18 07:12:58   error  : Creation of listener 'Read-Connection-Listener' for service 'Read Connection Router' failed, because both 'socket' and 'port' are defined. Only either one is allowed.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   error  : Creation of listener 'Write-Connection-Listener' for service 'Write Connection Router' failed, because both 'socket' and 'port' are defined. Only either one is allowed.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   error  : Creation of listener 'RW-Split-Listener' for service 'RW Split Router' failed, because both 'socket' and 'port' are defined. Only either one is allowed.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   notice : Monitor 'Galera-Monitor' is missing the 'journal_max_age' parameter, using default value of 28800 seconds.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   notice : Monitor 'Galera-Monitor' is missing the 'script_timeout' parameter, using default value of 90 seconds.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   error  : 3 errors were encountered while processing the configuration file '/etc/maxscale.cnf'.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   error  : Failed to open, read or process the MaxScale configuration file /etc/maxscale.cnf. Exiting.
2018-05-18 07:12:58   MariaDB MaxScale is shut down.
----------------------------------------------------
me@mdbec-max1:~$ maxadmin
Unable to connect to MaxScale at /tmp/maxadmin.sock: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE 4**

```
[maxscale]
threads=4
datadir=/var/lib/maxscale/data/


#[MySQL Monitor]
#type=monitor
#module=mysqlmon
#servers=server1,server2,server3
#user=myuser
#passwd=mypwd
#monitor_interval=10000
#backend_connect_timeout=
#backend_read_timeout=
#backend_write_timeout=
#detect_replication_lag=
#detect_stale_master=

[Galera Monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxscalemonitor
passwd=I-DELETE-THIS-LINE
monitor_interval=1000
#disable_master_failback=


[qla]
type=filter
module=qlafilter
filebase=/tmp/QueryLog

[fetch]
type=filter
module=regexfilter
match=fetch
replace=select

[hint]
type=filter
module=hintfilter



[Write Connection Router]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxscalemonitor
passwd=I-DELETE-THIS-LINE
router_options=master
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
version_string=10.2.14-MariaDB Cluster

[Read Connection Router]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxscalemonitor
passwd=I-DELETE-THIS-LINE
router_options=synced
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
version_string=10.2.14-MariaDB Cluster

[RW Split Router]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxscalemonitor
passwd=I-DELETE-THIS-LINE
max_slave_connections=100%
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
version_string=10.2.14-MariaDB Cluster
router_options=disable_sescmd_history=true
#use_sql_variables_in=master
#max_slave_replication_lag=21
#filters=hint|fetch|qla
#router_options=slave_selection_criteria=LEAST_CURRENT_OPERATIONS


[CLI]
type=service
router=cli


[RW Split Listener]
type=listener
service=RW Split Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4006
socket=/var/lib/maxscale/rwsplit.sock

[Write Connection Listener]
type=listener
service=Write Connection Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4007
socket=/var/lib/maxscale/writeconn.sock

[Read Connection Listener]
type=listener
service=Read Connection Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4008
socket=/var/lib/maxscale/readconn.sock

[CLI Listener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
socket=/tmp/maxadmin.sock

[MaxInfo]
type=service
router=maxinfo

[MaxInfo JSON Listener]
type=listener
service=MaxInfo
protocol=HTTPD
port=8003
address=localhost


[CLIUnixListener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
socket=default

[CLIInetListener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
address=localhost
port=6603


[db1]
type=server
address=172.16.4.4
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[db2]
type=server
address=172.16.4.5
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[db3]
type=server
address=172.16.4.6
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add a rule to allow a connection from your remote ip

Comment: @Hackerman Where should I add a rule? I set an public loadbalancer and normally this loadbalancer should accept all connections from any ip - or not?

Comment: Take a look at this guide, you should be able to connect following the `Direct MariaDB/MySQL client access` part.

Comment: @Hackerman Which guide do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the link...this one https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-tx-cluster-in-azure-quick-guide/

Comment: @Hackerman this is exactly what I have done. My loadbalancer is set to public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sokolata,

I found the issues with your configs. Please, remove the port or the socket from the listener's snippets. If you would like to have a port for a network listener and the socket for a localhost connection, you need to create separate snippets. Below, I adapted a little bit your configs to my labs and it's working as you can see below:

**maxscale.cnf**

```
[maxscale]
threads=4
#datadir=/var/lib/maxscale/data/

[Galera Monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxmon
passwd=2C894F278CEC5B974966EC969E006E37
monitor_interval=1000

[qla]
type=filter
module=qlafilter
filebase=/tmp/QueryLog

[fetch]
type=filter
module=regexfilter
match=fetch
replace=select

[hint]
type=filter
module=hintfilter

[Write Connection Router]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxusr
passwd=2C894F278CEC5B974966EC969E006E37
router_options=master
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
version_string=10.2.14-MariaDB Cluster

[Read Connection Router]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxusr
passwd=2C894F278CEC5B974966EC969E006E37
router_options=synced
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
version_string=10.2.14-MariaDB Cluster

[RW Split Router]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=db1,db2,db3
user=maxusr
passwd=2C894F278CEC5B974966EC969E006E37
max_slave_connections=100%
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
version_string=10.2.14-MariaDB Cluster
router_options=disable_sescmd_history=true

[CLI]
type=service
router=cli

[RW Split Listener]
type=listener
service=RW Split Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4006
#socket=/var/lib/maxscale/rwsplit.sock

[Write Connection Listener]
type=listener
service=Write Connection Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4007
#socket=/var/lib/maxscale/writeconn.sock

[Read Connection Listener]
type=listener
service=Read Connection Router
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4008
#socket=/var/lib/maxscale/readconn.sock

[CLI Listener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
socket=/tmp/maxadmin.sock

[CLIUnixListener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
socket=default

[CLIInetListener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
address=localhost
port=6603

[db1]
type=server
address=10.136.85.157
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[db2]
type=server
address=10.136.87.40
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[db3]
type=server
address=10.136.80.203
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend
```

**maxscale.log**

```
MariaDB MaxScale  /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log  Sun May 20 13:30:49 2018
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Working directory: /var/log/maxscale
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : The collection of SQLite memory allocation statistics turned off.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Threading mode of SQLite set to Multi-thread.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : MariaDB MaxScale 2.2.5 started
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : MaxScale is running in process 24042
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Configuration file: /root/maxscale/configs/test.cnf
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Log directory: /var/log/maxscale
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Data directory: /var/lib/maxscale
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Module directory: /usr/lib64/maxscale
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Service cache: /var/cache/maxscale
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loading /root/maxscale/configs/test.cnf.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Number of threads set to 4, which is greater than the number of processors available: 1
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: Galera Monitor
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: Write Connection Router
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: Read Connection Router
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: RW Split Router
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: RW Split Listener
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: Write Connection Listener
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: Read Connection Listener
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Whitespace in object names is deprecated, converting to hyphens: CLI Listener
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : /root/maxscale/configs/test.cnf.d does not exist, not reading.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [cli] Initialise CLI router module
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module cli: V1.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libcli.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [readwritesplit] Initializing statement-based read/write split router module.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module readwritesplit: V1.1.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libreadwritesplit.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [readconnroute] Initialise readconnroute router module.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module readconnroute: V1.1.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libreadconnroute.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module hintfilter: V1.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libhintfilter.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module regexfilter: V1.1.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libregexfilter.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module qlafilter: V1.1.1 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libqlafilter.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [galeramon] Initialise the MySQL Galera Monitor module.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module galeramon: V2.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libgaleramon.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Protocol module 'mysqlbackend' has been deprecated, use 'mariadbbackend' instead.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module mariadbbackend: V2.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libmariadbbackend.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module MySQLBackendAuth: V1.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libmysqlbackendauth.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module maxscaled: V2.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libmaxscaled.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module MaxAdminAuth: V2.1.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libmaxadminauth.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Protocol module 'mysqlclient' has been deprecated, use 'mariadbclient' instead.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module mariadbclient: V1.1.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libmariadbclient.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module MySQLAuth: V1.1.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libmysqlauth.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Monitor 'Galera-Monitor' is missing the 'journal_max_age' parameter, using default value of 28800 seconds.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Monitor 'Galera-Monitor' is missing the 'script_timeout' parameter, using default value of 90 seconds.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : No query classifier specified, using default 'qc_sqlite'.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Loaded module qc_sqlite: V1.0.0 from /usr/lib64/maxscale/libqc_sqlite.so
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: Removing stale journal file for monitor 'Galera-Monitor'.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Using encrypted passwords. Encryption key: '/var/lib/maxscale/.secrets'.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Starting a total of 4 services...
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [MySQLAuth] [Write-Connection-Router] Loaded 7 MySQL users for listener Write-Connection-Listener.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Listening for connections at [::]:4007 with protocol MySQL
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Service 'Write-Connection-Router' started (1/4)
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [MySQLAuth] [Read-Connection-Router] Loaded 7 MySQL users for listener Read-Connection-Listener.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Listening for connections at [::]:4008 with protocol MySQL
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Service 'Read-Connection-Router' started (2/4)
2018-05-20 13:30:49   warning: [readwritesplit] Router options for readwritesplit are deprecated.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : [MySQLAuth] [RW-Split-Router] Loaded 7 MySQL users for listener RW-Split-Listener.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Listening for connections at [::]:4006 with protocol MySQL
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Service 'RW-Split-Router' started (3/4)
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Listening for connections at [/tmp/maxadmin.sock]:0 with protocol MaxScale Admin
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Listening for connections at [/tmp/maxadmin.sock]:0 with protocol MaxScale Admin
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Listening for connections at [localhost]:6603 with protocol MaxScale Admin
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Service 'CLI' started (4/4)
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Started MaxScale log flusher.
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : Started REST API on [127.0.0.1]:8989
2018-05-20 13:30:49   notice : MaxScale started with 4 worker threads, each with a stack size of 8388608 bytes.
2018-05-20 13:30:50   notice : Server changed state: db1[10.136.85.157:3306]: new_master. [Running] -> [Master, Synced, Running]
2018-05-20 13:30:50   notice : Server changed state: db2[10.136.87.40:3306]: new_slave. [Running] -> [Slave, Synced, Running]
2018-05-20 13:30:50   notice : Server changed state: db3[10.136.80.203:3306]: new_slave. [Running] -> [Slave, Synced, Running]
```

I tested connectivity with the three listeners:

**4006**

```
[root@mxs01 ~]# for i in {1..10}; do mysql -ubianchi -p -h10.136.72.138 -P 4006 -e "select @@hostname\G"; done
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
```

**4007**

```
[root@mxs01 ~]# for i in {1..10}; do mysql -ubianchi -p -h10.136.72.138 -P 4007 -e "select @@hostname\G"; done
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n01
```

**4008**

```
[root@mxs01 ~]# for i in {1..10}; do mysql -ubianchi -p -h10.136.72.138 -P 4008 -e "select @@hostname\G"; done
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n03
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n03
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n03
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n03
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n02
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@hostname: n03
```

Give it a try and let us know how it goes, cheers!

Comment: This works! So the standard configuration on azure is not working as they should.

Comment: Remember that the MariaDB TX 2.0 is used for tests purposes and it's not ready for production.

Comment: Really? The Support told me that I can use MariaDB TX 2.0 for production. What you recomment to use for production?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please enable temporarily the log_info on Maxscale Instances and attempt the connection again? With the log_info enabled, it's going to add events to the Maxscale log (/var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log) that shows more details about why the request cannot be routed to the backends.

The below command will enable the log dynamically:

```
$ maxadmin enable log-priority info
```

The below command will disable the log dynamically:

```
$ maxadmin disable log-priority info
```

Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Hello Wagner, I create a new "answer". Thank you.

Comment: I Put the Update in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

To run the Maxadmin client, first of all, you need to allocate the CLI Router and a listener for that router, as described at:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-21-maxscale-21-cli/.

The configurations to be added to the /etc/maxscale.cnf are the below ones:

```
[CLI]
type=service
router=cli

[CLIUnixListener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
socket=default

[CLIInetListener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
address=localhost
port=6603
```

Add the above to the /etc/maxscale.cnf and restart maxscale. After that, they the below approach:

```
$ maxadmin -uadmin -pmariadb
```

or

```
$ sudo maxadmin
```

About the error when creating the listeners, could you please share the Maxscale configuration file here and then, I can have a look? Check if Maxscale can create the CLI Router listener I suggested above.

Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: See my first post Update 2. Thank you

Comment: You will find my full maxscale.cnf in my first post Update 4

Answer (score 0):

The support told you, you mean, the Microsoft Azure Support, right? By the way, my recommendation is that you got for a small project, setting up your own VNet on Azure, spinning up 4 new VMs, being 1 Maxscale and 3 others for a MariaDB Cluster. Once you have the VMs defined, set up the MariaDB Official Repo on all servers:

```
curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash
```

Setup MariaDB Servers and the MariaDB Maxscale, set up the cluster, create the Maxscale users and use the configurations we defined here to make it work.

Go and have fun.

Comment: No, it was the MariaDB Support/Sale.